# How to resolve Linux web server lost network pockets

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, web-server

My website is hosted on a Ubuntu web server. The web server is installed on VMware from the win server 2012. Server and web server are in same subnet, `20.235.*.*`.

Yesterday I restarted the web server. Now I can access the website at home, but cannot access it at the office (all office computers are in the same subnet). My office subnet is `192.168.*.*`.

I guess the problem is lost pockets from web server. I checked the network connection from server, there has a disabled VMware network adapter that ip address is `192.168.*.*`. Maybe this is the problem?

Can anybody can help me?

Comment: Have you tried enabling the disabled `192.168.*.*` VMware network adapter?  (Was it enabled before you rebooted?)

Comment: @Katherine yes, I tried enabled the 192.168.*.*, not working. BTW, the web server use bridged to connect network. I also tried change Nat network to 192.168.*.*, the web server cannot connect to network. I didn't change anything, only restart web server....

Comment: Can you ping both the Windows server and Ubuntu server? Was there perhaps iptables rules in place which weren't saved before the reboot?

Comment: @MarkoPolo, I can ping, ssh, ftp from 192.168 to Ubuntu Server ip address and host name, also flush iptables, still not working:(

Comment: Ok, can you telnet from the internal network to port 80 (or whatever port the server is listening on?). If not, please post the output of `iptables -nvL`.

Comment: @MarkoPolo, thanks, I can telnet to port 80 use host name. This is the web server output of iptables -nvL: 

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 688 packets, 75588 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 738 packets, 121K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Comment: If you can telnet to the server on port 80, everything should be working correctly unless there is some kind of application or MTU issue. Can you take a wireshark capture or tcpdump on client and server when you make a request and upload it somewhere.

Comment: @MarkoPolo, when I telnet to the host name on port 80, screen displayed blank, then entered exit, it shows page html code. This means I can telnet to the server on port 80 correctly? I use tcpdump on server, but don't understand how to find the problem...BTW, I found when I visit hostname by browser from 192.168. I got this site can't be reached. When I visit ip address it shows only text but no picture